# Adjusting Pivot Chart on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

[image]

I´ve been trying to
a.) see the value in the legend (e.g. Blue = Name A)
b.) remove the numbers (ids) at the x-axis

Can anyone guide me in the right direction / help me with this?

Thank you!

EDIT:

The initial data looks like this:

[image]

I created a pivot table that is then using SET as columns. Therefore I am not able to the option "Use first row as header".

I found the reason why the x-axis has the values on it:
[image]

EDIT 2:
Thanks for the answer!

Problem is that I can´t choose "row 2 as an option"!

(FYI: Set = Name)

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: We would need how the values in the middle axis were displayed in the chart options, I would edit the answer once a sample is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Given the table that was sent, you can generate a pivot table with this setup to prepare for graph generation:

[image]

Then generated a graph with these settings. Note that `Use Row 2 as Headers` and `Use Column A as Labels` are both checked:

[image]

The X-axis scale are automatic though, they will be adjusted based on the number of entries (and the value) in the defined X-axis.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Can you have a look at my edit @carlos-m

Comment: Thanks for the sample table, I edited my answer to generate a graph similar to your expectation. @m

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I can´t choose "Use row 2 as headers". Please see in my second edit. FYI: the column "Set" is called "Name" in my data.

Comment: The option is correct, you just need to remove the ````Name```` column from the series list.

Comment: No its like it would say "Set" instead of "Set A" for you. If I remove it i Will loose the first column of data

Comment: Ah I get it. Your range should start at row 2 instead of row 1. In the example it would be A2:E4. The first column would be the X-axis. The rest of the columns would be in the series.

Comment: Okay that works!
Still don´t get why its not recognizing this on its own! Anyway thanks a lot! :-)